# android webview how to integrate onpagefinished?

Tags: android, webview

i have a android webview app, when I open the app, a blank white screen comes up until the url has loaded.

Now Im trying to display simply some text ("website is loading") on this white screen until the website has fully loaded

Read a lot of threads but can't get to it to work with my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    String loadUrl = "http://mywebsite.com";


    WebSettings webSettings = mwebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    try {
        // load the url

            mwebview.loadUrl(loadUrl);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    this.mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
            String url2 = "http://mywebsite.com/";
            if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        }

    });

}
```

any quick solutions for this?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

              }

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            }

        });
```

Comment: Oh nice, very simple. You are using OnProgressChanged, is there any difference between using onpagefinished and OnProgressChanged?

Comment: onPageFinished is invoked once the url is loaded to the webview, onProgressChanged is invoked every time when there is a progress in loading the url, once the progress reaches 100 then onPageFinished is called.